# Hide an UL just in one DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At the moment I have this code:

```
<body>

<ul id="menu">
   <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#section1">1</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#section2">2</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#section3">3</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="4thpage"><a href="#section4">4</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="fullpage">
   <div class="section" id="section0"><h1>0</h1></div>
   <div class="section" id="section1">
      <div class="slide" id="slide1"><h1>1.a</h1></div>
      <div class="slide" id="slide2"><h1>1.b</h1></div>
   </div>
   <div class="section" id="section2"><h1>2</h1></div>
   <div class="section" id="section3"><h1>3</h1></div>
   <div class="section" id="section4"><h1>4</h1></div>
</div>

</body>
```

So, I have something like an intro in section0 and the rest of the page in the other sections. Also I have a menu but I just one to hide it in section0.

I have done this using JS:

```
$('#section0').on("mouseover",function(){ ;
    $('#menu').hide();
});
$('#section0').on("mouseout",function(){
    $('#menu').show();
});
```

And also this:

```
$('#section0').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#menu').show();
});
$('#section0').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#menu').hide();
});
```

And both solutions work but not perfectly. For example, if someone goes down the page using the wheel and he or she does not move the mouse (just the wheel), menu will not be shown. Or if someone goes up, for example, to the address bar, menu will be shown.

Could you tell me any tip or advice to do it properly? Thank you in advance and forgive my english.

Comment: Why not to use css? #section0:hover { display: none;}

Comment: @Cuzi I have already tryed that but how can I relate `#section0` with `#menu`?

Comment: in that case i would recommended to use toggle class $('#section0').on("mouseover mouseout",function(){ ;
    $('#menu').toggleClass("hide");
}); [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/413h7tzz/)

Comment: you want to hide the till the time section0 is visible or when the mouse is over the section0?

Comment: @Zariweya sounds like click with toggle would fix the issue.

Comment: @Cuzi thank you again but your solution is pretty similar to mine.It does not work "perfectly".

Comment: @MukeshAgarwal exactly, I just want to hide the menu when section0 is visible to the user.

Comment: @sdcr thank you for your answer but that is not an option.

Comment: @MukeshAgarwal or when someone goes out of the page, to the address bar, for example.

Sorry, I forgot that point in my last comment.

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't understood u as well, what you mean. "Perfect"?

Comment: @Cuzi with your code happens the same than with mine. If I am in section0 and  I use the wheel of my mouse to go down the page and I do not move my mouse, I mean the pointer, the menu will not be shown. And if I am at section0 and I go to the address bar the menu will be shown. In the same way, if I am in section1, for example, and I go to section0 using the wheel of my mouse without moving the pointer, menu will not be hidden. Perfect is when all that things do not happen xD.

Comment: So if the pointer is on each section the whole menu should be hidden?

Comment: @Cuzi check this: http://zariweya.neocities.org/prueba/prueba.html I just want to show menu in sections 1, 2, 3 and 4. Just there. Without needing to move my mouse or whatever. In my web, when I use my wheel to go down from section0 to section1 it does not show the menu. But when I use my wheel to go down from section1 to section2 it does show the menu. You know what I mean?

Comment: set to your body class="fp-viewing-intro" from before the loading and in the css body:not(fp-viewing-intro) #menu { display: block; } body.fp-viewing-intro #menu { display: none; }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71454/discussion-between-zariweya-and-cuzi).